# Determine role of stateful replica in service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a stateful service in Service Fabric with multiple partitions and replicas. I have configured it so that both the Primary and ActiveSecondary replicas expose their endpoints. The purpose is so that I can leverage the secondary replicas for read operations.

The problem I'm having is that inside the service I want to be able to tell it is a Primary or ActiveSecondary because some shared defaulting code needs to not run for the secondary replicas. (Because inserting defaults into the ReliableStateManager throws on secondaries.)

Can I determine the Replica Role at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `OnChangeRoleAsync` and check the `ReplicaRole` parameter. Note that:

- The role can change during the lifetime of a service (e.g. secondary promoted to primary)
- `RunAsync` is only executed on primary replicas (will be cancelled if the role changes) - **so you can safely place your initialization code there**
- For more advanced scenarios, you can also check the `Partition`'s `ReadStatus` and `WriteStatus`

Comment: Looks like you can get the partition number by looking at the HighKey and the LowKey.  You can also determine if you are a primary or replica, but can you know that you are replia #2 out of 4  (for example).    I'd like

Comment: Is there a way to know the current `ReplicaRole` in `OnChangeRoleAsync`? The parameter it takes is `newRole`, but I want to know the current role.