# Getting multiple Service Fabric reliable dictionary notifications for single entry in the reliable dictionary

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I have stateful service fabric service with replica count is 3.

In this stateful service, I have a reliable dictionary.

I want to track notifications for each CRUD operation which performed on the reliable dictionary. Followed the below link to integrate reliable dictionary notifications,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-notifications

If I use a one-node cluster and replica count is 1, I will be getting one notification for each operation (Create, Update, Delete).

But If I use five-node cluster and replica count is 3, I will be getting three notifications for each operation, which is causing me to duplicate record in my business logic, I need only one notification for each operation.

I am expecting it is getting a notification for each replica when the dictionary has been updated.

Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue?

Comment: Your should only subscribe to the events from the primary replice.

Comment: How Can I differentiate primary replica events and secondary replica

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636023/determine-role-of-stateful-replica-in-service-fabric. Best bet is RunAsync as stated in the linked answer.